# Make the rep display bold again

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, arqade-migration

With the site redesign, I noticed that on the main site (but not on meta) rep now does not show as bold. Can someone please fix this?

Comment: +1. `font-weight` is set to `normal` in the `.reputation-score` CSS rule.

Comment: Still bold in meta. Must have been an oversight.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too

Comment: It's fixed now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that was done a long time ago.